# Pokemon Go: Everything loads except for gyms

Tags: pokemon-go

When I try battling in a gym, it shows me the picture of the battlefield and nothing else. My connection is fine as I can walk around and catch Pokemon and go to Pokestops. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Could you give a bit more information please? It might be that the gym is currently bugged, this can happen sometimes when several people (belonging to different teams) are battling over a gym.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks hmm, I think that's the problem, since the gym changes team every 10 minutes :|

Comment: I've had this issue before too. Usually it was an issue connecting with Niantic servers, even though I had full cell coverage. I just waited a little while and the issue resolved itself